# How to autofocus with highlight blue color on today date in datepicker of angular material?

Tags: angular

I want today date should be highlighted by default even without selecting it. and if i'll select other date then other date should become highlight. I am using angular material datepicker. Is there any way to do it? My code sample is:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

[this sample link is from https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview](https://stackblitz.com/angular/oavmkdkdraq?file=app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts)

I want output some thing like the screen shot, but highlight color should be go to selected date after selecting any other date.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ng-deep for the above case.
You have two classes here
We need to override these classes and provide our styles.

1.mat-calendar-body-today
2.mat-calendar-body-selected

As the name specifies to today's date class **mat-calendar-body-today** is attached and Similarly to selected date class **mat-calendar-body-selected** is attached.

Update:- 
I have tested it from my end and it works...

Add below code in your css
This will hide this class **mat-calendar-body-today** which we don't need.

```html
::ng-deep .mat-calendar-body-today:not(.mat-calendar-body-selected) { display: none; }
```

Not just bind your datepicker with an [(ngModel]) attribute and initialize that variable to today's date. This will make today's day as selected.

```js
selectedBefore = new Date();
```

```html
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="selectedBefore" [matDatepicker]="beforeDate" id="beforeDate" name="before" placeholder="Before Date" (dateChange)="onDateChange($event)" disabled>
```

Comment: Actually this is not my issue, I want to highlight current date by default and when any date is selected then that highlight should transfer to selected date and only selected date should be highlighted not current date now. I think you understand my requirement now.

Comment: that is what you can do initially you can change the color and once on first select event you can change the style of this class to display:none

Comment: actually i don't know the exact code for select event to remove the highlighted today date in angular or jquary. can you please send me the code for the select event.

Comment: override this class mat-calendar-body-selected also and style it in the same way. As this is the class that get attached to selected class. You need .mat-calendar-body-today only initialially ...after that it's no use as you will always have something selected and selected date will have this 'mat-calendar-body-selected' class

Comment: you can attach a (change) or (select) event to your datepicker .Pass event value.From event value you can get class list of all the classes and you can remove this particular class. Please Google,It not big issue,You can easily solve it now.

Comment: tried a lot from 2 days if you get the solution then please post.

Comment: sure..I'll create a demo and update you regarding the same

Comment: can you update it on stackblitz link please, it is not working for me what I required.

Comment: import formsmodule in your app.modules as to use [(ngModel)] we need FormsModule. I don't have stackblitz nor fiddle

Comment: yes but i didn't get that how to write "onDateChange($event)" in ts file. can you please update ts,html and css file.

Comment: You don't need to do that now..just add the css...add ngModel in input tag.Place a variable there and initialize that variable to new Date().That's it.

Comment: Follow only the above three steps

Comment: I have done dat because I had to do some formatting of date..You just add ngModel and assign it to a variable

Comment: Thankyou Swapnil for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

**style.css**

```
.mat-calendar-body-cell-content.mat-calendar-body-today{
  background-color: green !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

**[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-autofocus-with-highlight-blue-color-on-today-date-in-dat?file=app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html)**

Comment: Actually this is not my issue, I want to highlight current date by default and when any date is selected then that highlight should transfer to selected date and only selected date should be highlighted not current date now. I think you understand my requirement now.

Comment: Thankyou but our requirement is by default current date should be highlighted and if select any other date then that date should become highlight and current date should not highlight, but here current date is not highlighting by default in you link. please make current date should highlight by default without selecting any date and this highlight should go when we select other date.

Comment: you can pass default date is today by date = new FormControl(new Date()); check link again

Comment: Here by default today date should not come in input field, but here today date is displaying in put field. I think we have to use some thing like " select event to remove this today's class using jquery or angular." If u can please update the link.

Comment: Thankyou Krishna for your cooperation

Answer (score 0):

There is a much cleaner and simpler solution:

```
@Input() dateClass
```

You provide a function that gets called for each date in the current display, and returns a css class to apply to that date.

For example, to highlight today's date, add this function:

```
applyCss(d: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses {
    if (d == new Date()) {
        return 'your-css-class';
    }
}
```

In your template, add this:

```
<mat-datepicker [dateClass]="applyCss"></mat-datepicker>
```

To change the highlight to the currently selected date, you can bind a class member to your date field, or hook into the dateChange event emitter of matDatepickerInput, and in your function you can apply the css class to only that date.

Bear in mind that because of View Encapsulation, your css class may need to be in a global file and not the css file associated with your component