# Angular datepicker setDate

Tags: angular, date, datepicker

I have a screen with a datapicker. When I already have a data parameter it selects me 2 dates in my calendar: the date parameter plus the date of the day. How to do if I have a date as a parameter so that it selects me as the date as a parameter and not also the date of the day

```
    <mat-label>Select a date</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker"
        [(ngModel)]="myDate"
        (dateChange)="onChange($event)"
        placeholder="">
        <mat-datepicker #picker ></mat-datepicker>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker" >

        </mat-datepicker-toggle>
```

[image]

Comment: simply give value to the variable "myDate", remember that is an **object Date** of javaScript and it's possible your data parameter was a string, Inn this case, you need make something like `myDate=new Date(myparameter)`

Comment: Precisely my date has a value when I arrive on my form. So it select me myDate and the date of the day

Comment: ::glups:: sorry, I don't understand you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like use ::ng-deep, so my aproach is add in styles.css (to apply to all the application) some like

```
.noTodayDatepicker .mat-calendar-body-today:not(.mat-calendar-body-selected){
    border-color:transparent!important;
}
.noTodayDatepicker .mat-calendar-body-today:not(:hover):not(.mat-calendar-body-selected){
  background-color:transparent!important;
}
.noTodayDatepicker .mat-calendar-body-today.mat-calendar-body-selected {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Then you can use pannelClass

```
  <mat-datepicker #picker panelClass="noTodayDatepicker"></mat-datepicker>
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vpzhwe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to this question and answer :
[How to autofocus with highlight blue color on today date in datepicker of angular material?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52109246/how-to-autofocus-with-highlight-blue-color-on-today-date-in-datepicker-of-angular)

Angular Material will apply styling to today's date, it does not mean that the date is selected it just appears a certain way because of its CSS

You can target the selected today node in your component's CSS by adding this and change it to look the way you need it to look.

```
::ng-deep.mat-calendar-body-today:not(.mat-calendar-body-selected) {
  background-color: white;
}
```